# How do I install opensuse using lubuntu?

Tags: command-line, opensuse, live-usb, lubuntu

I've been trying to create a bootable disc, first usb, then dvd, and even tried the over the net/no physical media thing.

I want to try opensuse because some software just doesn't work properly with lubuntu on my laptop. It might be my old laptop; I don't know. It worked wonderfully with Meerkat.

I have been trying to create the disc for nearly 5 hours now and I just can't.

**All** my USBs are apparently off limits. Lubuntu won't let me do anything on any of them, because I had been using them on windows I guess I can't use them on lubuntu.

Also tried to format a dvd+rw and the system wont let me. It's a DVD +RW. I mean, this **never** happened on Ubuntu or even Windows.

( OK, the rant is over.)

I really need a new system, and wanted to try OpenSuse, but how can I install one if lubuntu won't let me do anything?

How can I successfully create a bootable dvd or usb?

I tried command lines, I tried the create disc software, two of them, one  just get's stuck on "downloading" and won't go anywhere the other tells me I don't have permission or that the disk doesn't exist.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the most success over the years using growisofs.  It's in a package called dvd+rw-tools.

Install that first of all.

Having done that it should be a matter of running growisofs like so:

```
growisofs -Z /dev/sr0=mysuseinstall.iso
```

Replace 'mysuseinstall.iso' with your actual iso filename you want to burn.

There should be no need to format the disc, as the iso will contain the filesystem you need plus its contents.

You may well need to precede the command with 'sudo ' if you don't have user access to write to /dev/dvd.  In which case, it'll ask for your password - use the same password you use to log on.

Comment: does it work with DVDs only or can I create a live USB as well?

Comment: The command I've given is unlikely to do anything useful with USB.  I've never done that myself so can't really help you if that's what you need to do.